# Retrieving strings from an array in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I am using meteor and `ajduke:bootstrap-tagsinput`for my tagging system.

**[ajduke:bootstrap-tagsinput example page](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)**

I am inserting the tags as arrays using `True Multiple Value` from the above link.

My tags are inserted into the collection as following

```
Posts
    tags (array)
        0: sometag (string)
        1: sometag (string)
        2: sometag (string)
        //and so forth
```

I need to find a way to retrieve each strings to the following format so that I can re-input these values to the tags input.

I need to do this because I want my users to be able to edit their tags when they edit their posts.

```
["sometag", "sometag", "sometag", and so forth]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `aldeed:autoform` package to render your forms you can use the `yogiben:autoform-tags` package to seamlessly integrate the bootstrap-tagsinput library with autoform.

Just install the autoform-tags package:

```
meteor add yogiben:autoform-tags
```

Then, in your form all you need is:

```
{{>afQuickField name="tags" type="tags" }}
```